# Get function name from DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, function

I want to get function name of the exception thrown from dll in asp.net.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to get the name of the method that threw the exception?

Comment: Yes, I need the name of the method in dll that throw the exception

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of the Stack Trace

[Exception.StackTrace Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx)

[StackTrace Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=VS.71).aspx)

> Represents a stack trace, which is an
>   ordered collection of one or more
>   stack frames.

[StackFrame Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx)

> A StackFrame is created and pushed on
>   the call stack for every function call
>   made during the execution of a thread.
>   The stack frame always includes
>   MethodBase information, and optionally
>   includes file name, line number, and
>   column number information.
>
> StackFrame information will be most
>   informative with Debug build
>   configurations. By default, Debug
>   builds include debug symbols, while
>   Release builds do not. The debug
>   symbols contain most of the file,
>   method name, line number, and column
>   information used in constructing
>   StackFrame objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class from the exception and analyze the frames.

For example:

```
public void Throw()
{
    throw new MyException();
}

public void CallThrow()
{
    Throw();
}

[Test]
public void GetThrowingMethodName()
{
    try
    {
        CallThrow();
        Assert.Fail("Should have thrown");
    }
    catch (MyException e)
    {
        MethodBase deepestMethod = new StackTrace(e).GetFrame(0).GetMethod();
        string deepestMethodName = deepestMethod.Name;
        Assert.That(deepestMethodName, Is.EqualTo("Throw"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I cant get the name of the method, tell me how to get name of the method from DLL that throw exception.

Comment: @ram, what's the result you're getting? Can you post an example of you're code and the call to the external assembly that throws the exception?

Comment: Here my example code:

void test()
{
  /* Exception Comes here */
}
public class method{
void load()
 {
   test();
 }
}

Here class name'method' was a dll file,im getting the exception from the method 'test()'. But the stack trace returns the name of the method as 'load()'. I need to get the method name 'test()'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try stacktrace object with the help of system.diagnostic namespace here is the linqpad testing source code that you can try out.

```
void Main()
{
    try {
        test();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name.Dump();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here


public void test()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`StackTrace.GetFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe%28VS.71%29.aspx) Method